# Received unregistered task of type 'dividends_project.run_yahoo_request_for_stock_info_task'

Tags: python, redis, celery, django-celery

I have worked through someone else's solution to this and nothing has helped. I am getting error

```
The delivery info for this task is:
{'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'celery'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cchilders/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 591, in on_task_received
    strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: 'dividends_project.run_yahoo_request_for_stock_info_task'
[2022-09-04 08:36:23,589: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'dividends_project.run_yahoo_request_for_stock_info_task'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?
```

[image]

I have the following dividends_project/celery.py

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.apps import apps

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "dividends_project.settings")
app = Celery("dividends_project", include=['dividends_info.tasks'])
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
# app.autodiscover_tasks()
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: [n.name for n in apps.get_app_configs()])
```

dividends_project/init.py:

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ("celery_app",)
```

I have the following dividends_info/tasks.py:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'dividends_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()

import time

from celery import shared_task, group

from dividends_info.functions.stock_info import save_stock_info_data
from dividends_info.models import StockInfo


@shared_task()
def run_yahoo_request_for_stock_info_task(ticker):
    print(locals().keys())
    # time.sleep(7)
    print("celery task ran for ticker {ticker}".format(ticker=ticker))
    stock, created = StockInfo.objects.get_or_create(ticker=ticker)
    save_stock_info_data(ticker, stock)


tickers = ['A', 'AA', 'AAC', 'AAN', 'AAP', 'AAT', 'AB', 'AAB', 'ABBV', 'ABC']

@shared_task()
def run_task():
    tasks = []
    for ticker in tickers:
        tasks.append(run_yahoo_request_for_stock_info_task.signature((ticker,)))
    print("start chain_call")
    t = group(*tasks).apply_async()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_task()
```

Everything checks out in terminal

```
IPython 8.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from dividends_info.tasks import run_yahoo_request_for_stock_info_task

In [2]:                                                                                                     
Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)? 
cchilders@cchilders-HP-ProBook-450-G3 ~/projects/stocks_backend (celery_stock_search_api_calls)$ python3 manage.py check
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

redis-server is fine and from root directory I ran

```
python3 -m celery -A dividends_project worker --pool=gevent --concurrency=40 --loglevel=info
```

Comment: Could you try import `app` and use `@app.task` decorator in `dividends_info/tasks.py`, e.g. `from dividends_project.celery import app`, then 
`@app.task()` over `def run_yahoo_request_for_stock_info_task(ticker):`

Comment: ok i will try that tomorrow

Comment: is this `dividends_info` app added to the INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py?

Comment: I think last thing to check is worker command. Now you are calling worker with app name dividends_project, but better would be to provide module name with celery app object, i.e. `dividends_project.celery`

Comment: no dividends info isnt an app its the main project folder with settings.py

Comment: according to your screenshot, dividends_info is django app and dividends_project is django project folder

Comment: yes but the celery app is in dividends_project. should i move it to dividends_info? I also tried that on another branch and even that didnt work